# How do I add a custom folder tree to the Windows 10 File Explorer side panel?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive

OneDrive has its own folder tree on the sidebar in Windows 10's file explorer, but on my own computer something messed up, and the OneDrive folder tree no longer shows up. I'm now using InSync instead of the OneDrive app, and I'd like to add a replacement for that OneDrive space in the sidebar. It's wonderfully convenient to have, being able to open the entire cloud storage folder tree right there.

[image: onedrive's folder tree]

I tried looking online for a way to add my own custom folder tree to the sidebar, but couldn't find anything. Is it possible to do?

[image: Photoshopped screenshot of what I'm imagining]

Here is a photoshopped screenshot of what I want to do. (Note that the folder called "OneDrive" doesn't have the OneDrive logo. As far as Windows is aware, it's just another folder.)

Comment: Are you just trying to get your OneDrive folder back in your Explorer sidebar? Or are you trying to get a custom set of folders/paths of your own choosing? If the former, just repair OneDrive. If the latter, Microsoft has published their Devkits and open APIs and you'll need to use these.

Comment: @music2myear I had attempted to get the OneDrive folder back in my sidebar and it never worked, so I'm looking for a way to add a custom folder. (Gonna attempt Winaero Tweaker now, which harrymc suggested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the free
[Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836):

- Click *Explorer > Navigation Pane - Custom Items*
- Click *Add custom folder*
- Click *Browse* and select your folder
- Set the options *Display as* and *Icon* to specify how the new item will be named
  and show in the navigation pane
- Click *Add Folder*
- Re-open Explorer.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I just might give that dev a donation, that tweaker tool looks super handy

Comment: Thi si excellent - thank you. The only thing that is missing is the ability to set the order of items in the side panel (added folders are at the very bottom)